# react.js: How to bind passed-in event handler's this to child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here's my code:

```
var Outer = React.createClass({
    clickHandler: function(){
        console.log(this.props.name);
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div><Inner name="inner" clickHandler={this.clickHandler} /></div>;
    }
});

var Inner = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <div onClick={this.props.clickHandler}>This is Inner.</div>
    }
});
```

what i wanna do here is to print out the Inner's name. but the real result of this code always prints out the name of the Outer. I think if caused by the 'this'. How can I bind the 'this' to Inner?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Note that you can not bind this between components in React.

You could have a middle-function that sends back the property. This might be to recommend, since you explicitly can safe check the callback method that was passed as a prop(Which makes your code more portable).

```
var Outter = React.createClass({
    clickHandler: function(innerName){
        console.log(innerName);
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div><Inner name="inner" clickHandler={this.clickHandler} /></div>;
    }
});

var Inner = React.createClass({
    _clickHandler : function() { 
        /*
        Here you could add some validation that you truly have a callback in your props.
        if(_(this.props.clickHandler).isFunction() ) {
        }
        */
        this.props.clickHandler('innerName');
    },
    render: function(){
        return <div onClick={this._clickHandler}>This is Inner.</div>
    }
});
```

Comment: actually I did this before. but it still print the name of Outter and got a warning in the console: Warning: bind(): React component methods may only be bound to the component instance.   any idea?

Comment: Oh, my bad - I was unaware of this restriction with react. 
Well, the most pragmatic way to do this might be to add a middle-function that sends back the property. I updated my answer with another idea @WalnutZ

Comment: hey thanks , btw I found a way to do this. just move the clickHandler method into render(), make it a function. then use bind(this) in the Inner component. didn't get any waring and it printed the Inner name. But I don't know why this works actually...

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

The usecase in the question is a different one than reusing a function - where you would use mixins. It's rather providing a callback to a child node.

This sounds like a perfect use case for mixins. Create a mixin for your functionality:

```
var myClickHandlerMixin = {
    clickHandler: function () { /* ... */ }
};

var Outer = React.createClass({
    mixins: [myClickHandlerMixin],
    render: function() {
        return <div><Inner name="inner" onClick={this.clickHandler} /></div>;
    }
});

var Inner = React.createClass({
    mixins: [myClickHandlerMixin],
    render: function(){
        return <div onClick={this.clickHandler}>This is Inner.</div>
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not my goal. In face the Outter is a reusable component so the clickHandler may change everytime.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I guess there is no way around using `{this.clickHandler.bind(this)}` like the other answers suggested

Comment: But be aware that if you plan to hand the function further down to another child this won't work properly with the bound function

Answer (score 0):

You should pass what `Outer` needs explicitly from `Inner`. Both because that's basically your only option, and because it makes the intention more clear.

Something like:

```
var Outter = React.createClass({
    clickHandler: function(name){
        console.log(name);
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div><Inner name="inner" clickHandler={this.clickHandler} /></div>;
    }
});

var Inner = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <div onClick={this.props.clickHandler.bind(this, 'Inner')}>This is Inner.</div>
    }
});
```